# CodeIgniter Error: Trying to get property of non-object ,database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a car parts website with tecdoc database and I included a provider for the prices and stock,via their api.

I have an error when entering a product page

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Trying to get
>   property of non-object Filename: controllers/tree.php Line Number: 349

THis is the line on 349:

```
$this->db->where('PRI_ART_ID',$idarticolx->ART_ID);
```

This is the code:

```
        require_once APPPATH.'third_party/AutoNet.php';//$this->load->library('AutoNet');
        $autonet_api = get_rest_autonet($params);
        $result = json_decode($autonet_api,true);
        // echo '<pre>';
        // die(print_r($result));
        if ($result['Error']['HasError'] == false) {

            $articles=$result['ArticleOffers'];

            if (!isset($articles['Article'])) { // daca sunt mai multe rezultate
                for ($n=0;$n<count($articles);$n++){
                    if  ($articles[$n]['StockStateText'] != ''){
                        $this->db->select('A.*');
                        $this->db->select('B.adaos');
                        $this->db->from('tof_articles AS A');
                        $this->db->join('list_suppliers AS B','B.SUP_ID=A.ART_SUP_ID');
                        $this->db->where('A.AUG_NR',$articles[$n]['PartNo']);
                        $this->db->where('A.ART_SUP_ID',$articles[$n]['TDBrandId']);
                        $idarticolx=$this->db->get()->row();
                        // $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
                        // echo "select A.*, B.adaos form tof_articles AS A join list_suppliers AS B, B.SUP_ID=A.ART_SUP_ID where A.ART_ARTICLE_NR = '{$articles[$n]['PartNo']}' AND A.ART_SUP_ID '{$articles[$n]['TDBrandId']}'";
                        // echo "<pre>";
                        // die(print_r($idarticolx));
                        $this->db->select('*');
                        $this->db->from('list_prices AS A');
                        $this->db->where('PRI_ART_ID',$row['id_articol']);
                        $b=$this->db->get();
                        if ($b->num_rows() > 0) {
                            $this->db->from('list_prices');
                            $this->db->set('PRI_PRICE_AC');
                            $this->db->set('PRI_PRICE');
                            $this->db->set('id_furnizor', '43');
                            $this->db->set('last_update', time());
                            $this->db->set('ST_1', '1');
                            $this->db->where('PRI_ART_ID',$idarticolx->ART_ID);//this is line 349
                            $this->db->update();
                        } else {
                            $this->db->from('list_prices');
                            $this->db->set('PRI_ART_ID' , $row['id_articol']);
                            $this->db->set('PRI_PRICE_AC', $articles[$n]['PriceWoVat']);
                            $this->db->set('PRI_PRICE', ceil($articles[$n]['PriceWoVat']));
                            $this->db->set('id_furnizor', '43');
                            $this->db->set('last_update', time());
                            $this->db->set('ST_1', '1');

                            $this->db->insert();
                        }


                    }

                }

            } else { // daca este un singur rezultat

                if  ($articles['Description'] != ''){

                    $this->db->select('A.*');

                    $this->db->select('B.adaos');

                    $this->db->from('tof_articles AS A');

                    $this->db->join('list_suppliers AS B','B.SUP_ID=A.ART_SUP_ID');

                    $this->db->where('A.ART_ARTICLE_NR',$articles['Article']);

                    $this->db->where('A.ART_SUP_ID',$articles['Brand']);

                    $idarticolx=$this->db->get()->row();



                    $this->db->select('*');

                    $this->db->from('list_prices AS A');

                    $this->db->where('A.PRI_ART_ID',$idarticolx->ART_ID);

                    $b=$this->db->get();

                    if ($b->num_rows() > 0) {

                        $this->db->from('list_prices');

                        $this->db->set('PRI_PRICE_AC', $articles['PriceWithVAT']);

                        $this->db->set('PRI_PRICE', ceil($articles['PriceWithVAT']*(100+$idarticolx->adaos)/100));

                        $this->db->set('id_furnizor', '2');

                        $this->db->set('last_update', time());

                        $this->db->set('ST_1', '1');

                        $this->db->where('PRI_ART_ID', $idarticolx->ART_ID);

                        $this->db->update();

                    } else {

                        $this->db->from('list_prices');

                        $this->db->set('PRI_ART_ID', $idarticolx->ART_ID);

                        $this->db->set('PRI_PRICE_AC', $articles['PriceWithVAT']);

                        $this->db->set('PRI_PRICE', ceil($articles['PriceWithVAT']*(100+$idarticolx->adaos)/100));

                        $this->db->set('id_furnizor', '2');

                        $this->db->set('last_update', time());

                        $this->db->set('ST_1', '1');

                        $this->db->insert();

                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: did you load the db library ?

Comment: $this->load->database();

Comment: No ,The site was made by someoneelse and i'm tring to fix the error,No that code is not present , i will put the full tree.php code in 1 sec.

Comment: It says `$idarticolx` does not have any value;try to `var_dump($idarticolx)`

Comment: Also search with `Trying to get property of non-object` you will get lots of answer why that error happen

Comment: I tried meny solutions form the search of the error

Comment: @LiviuDaniel you tried many solutions? Did you checked what I said at my previous comment?what value you have `$idarticolx`?

Comment: i added this code ob_start();
   var_dump($idarticolx);
   $result = ob_get_contents(); and i get this error Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: idarticolx
Filename: controllers/tree.php
Line Number: 1054

Answer (score 0):

The problems arise when you assume everything worked in your code. In your case, you must validate all the data before using it, to make sure it exists.

**The first problem:**

```
$this->db->select('A.*');
$this->db->select('B.adaos');
$this->db->from('tof_articles AS A');
$this->db->join('list_suppliers AS B','B.SUP_ID=A.ART_SUP_ID');
$this->db->where('A.AUG_NR',$articles[$n]['PartNo']);
$this->db->where('A.ART_SUP_ID',$articles[$n]['TDBrandId']);
$idarticolx=$this->db->get()->row();
// $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
// echo "select A.*, B.adaos form tof_articles AS A join list_suppliers AS B, B.SUP_ID=A.ART_SUP_ID where A.ART_ARTICLE_NR = '{$articles[$n]['PartNo']}' AND A.ART_SUP_ID '{$articles[$n]['TDBrandId']}'";
// echo "<pre>";
// die(print_r($idarticolx));
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('list_prices AS A');
$this->db->where('PRI_ART_ID',$row['id_articol']);
$b=$this->db->get();
if ($b->num_rows() > 0) {
    $this->db->from('list_prices');
    $this->db->set('PRI_PRICE_AC');
    $this->db->set('PRI_PRICE');
    $this->db->set('id_furnizor', '43');
    $this->db->set('last_update', time());
    $this->db->set('ST_1', '1');
    $this->db->where('PRI_ART_ID',$idarticolx->ART_ID);//this is line 349
    $this->db->update();
} else {
    $this->db->from('list_prices');
    $this->db->set('PRI_ART_ID' , $row['id_articol']);
    $this->db->set('PRI_PRICE_AC', $articles[$n]['PriceWoVat']);
    $this->db->set('PRI_PRICE', ceil($articles[$n]['PriceWoVat']));
    $this->db->set('id_furnizor', '43');
    $this->db->set('last_update', time());
    $this->db->set('ST_1', '1');

    $this->db->insert();
}
```

You are assuming that in the variable `$idarticolx` there is a result.
Instead of:

```
if ($b->num_rows() > 0) {
```

use

```
if ($b->num_rows() > 0 && $idarticolx) {
```

**The second problem:**

```
if  ($articles['Description'] != ''){
    $this->db->select('A.*');
    $this->db->select('B.adaos');
    $this->db->from('tof_articles AS A');
    $this->db->join('list_suppliers AS B','B.SUP_ID=A.ART_SUP_ID');
    $this->db->where('A.ART_ARTICLE_NR',$articles['Article']);
    $this->db->where('A.ART_SUP_ID',$articles['Brand']);
    $idarticolx=$this->db->get()->row();

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('list_prices AS A');
    $this->db->where('A.PRI_ART_ID',$idarticolx->ART_ID);
    $b=$this->db->get();

    if ($b->num_rows() > 0) {
        $this->db->from('list_prices');
        $this->db->set('PRI_PRICE_AC', $articles['PriceWithVAT']);
        $this->db->set('PRI_PRICE', ceil($articles['PriceWithVAT']*(100+$idarticolx->adaos)/100));
        $this->db->set('id_furnizor', '2');
        $this->db->set('last_update', time());
        $this->db->set('ST_1', '1');
        $this->db->where('PRI_ART_ID', $idarticolx->ART_ID);
        $this->db->update();
    } else {
        $this->db->from('list_prices');
        $this->db->set('PRI_ART_ID', $idarticolx->ART_ID);
        $this->db->set('PRI_PRICE_AC', $articles['PriceWithVAT']);
        $this->db->set('PRI_PRICE', ceil($articles['PriceWithVAT']*(100+$idarticolx->adaos)/100));
        $this->db->set('id_furnizor', '2');
        $this->db->set('last_update', time());
        $this->db->set('ST_1', '1');
        $this->db->insert();
    }
}
```

You are assuming again that in the variable `$idarticolx` there is a result. The code should be:

```
if  ($articles['Description'] != ''){
    $this->db->select('A.*');
    $this->db->select('B.adaos');
    $this->db->from('tof_articles AS A');
    $this->db->join('list_suppliers AS B','B.SUP_ID=A.ART_SUP_ID');
    $this->db->where('A.ART_ARTICLE_NR',$articles['Article']);
    $this->db->where('A.ART_SUP_ID',$articles['Brand']);
    $idarticolx=$this->db->get()->row();

    if ($idarticolx) {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('list_prices AS A');
        $this->db->where('A.PRI_ART_ID',$idarticolx->ART_ID);
        $b=$this->db->get();

        if ($b->num_rows() > 0) {
            $this->db->from('list_prices');
            $this->db->set('PRI_PRICE_AC', $articles['PriceWithVAT']);
            $this->db->set('PRI_PRICE', ceil($articles['PriceWithVAT']*(100+$idarticolx->adaos)/100));
            $this->db->set('id_furnizor', '2');
            $this->db->set('last_update', time());
            $this->db->set('ST_1', '1');
            $this->db->where('PRI_ART_ID', $idarticolx->ART_ID);
            $this->db->update();
        } else {
            $this->db->from('list_prices');
            $this->db->set('PRI_ART_ID', $idarticolx->ART_ID);
            $this->db->set('PRI_PRICE_AC', $articles['PriceWithVAT']);
            $this->db->set('PRI_PRICE', ceil($articles['PriceWithVAT']*(100+$idarticolx->adaos)/100));
            $this->db->set('id_furnizor', '2');
            $this->db->set('last_update', time());
            $this->db->set('ST_1', '1');
            $this->db->insert();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, validate that `get_rest_autonet` function resturns a response and that `json_decode` decoded a json string.

**Never asume anything or your code will be a bomb and you will be a bad programmer.**

Answer (score -1):

I dont see in your code something like

```
$this->load->database();
```

or

```
$this->load->library('database');
```

you might have it in the autoload config but maybe its not there.
check your autoload config at 
application/config/autoload.php
and check if the database is in the array of `$autoload['libraries']`

Comment: Do not write answer from assumption write it as comment.This is not right answer though.If he did not load database the error will come to another line where he started to using `$this->db`.

Comment: This is in autoload.php  $autoload['libraries'] = array(

 'database',

 'cart',

 'session',

 'user_agent'

);

Comment: That's the best way of loading database.